# Basic javascript code on hidden field to stop simple bots signingup

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to have a hidden field in my code as below, that bots will fill in when submitting it. But i want javascript code to look at that field only for a value and if there is a value, create an alert or hide the submit button so the bot cannot signup at all.

I just tailored a mailchimp form to use.

```html
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://my.site/index.php/lists/ej8651mn51e/subscribe" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>


    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_8705ce44717aeac8551b690ed_1b95a85a92" tabindex="-1" value="erg34t34t3"></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: A bot isn't going to be put off by an alert or a hidden submit button

Comment: You say you've spent 'so much time' albet no evidence of an attempt in your post?

Comment: Couldn't you filter out the bots from the database?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are talking about using a **honeypot** technique to catch spam bots. But I think you are thinking about it slightly wrong. A bot with any level of sophistication should be able to submit a form without it having an explicit submit button. Further, a sophisticated spam bot will be able to bypass any client-side validation you attempt to perform prior to submitting the form, and will also likely ignore any seemingly meaningless alerts you present it.

Thus, you want to augment your client-side validation with server-side validation when using a honeypot. The idea is that a normal user won't enter anything into a hidden field, but a bot *might*, so if there is an unexpected value in it then the form submission is bogus.

If you are, however, stuck with client-side validation here are a few articles about implementing honeypots in JavaScript:

- https://lukehollenback.me/avoiding-bots-without-a-captcha/
- http://jennamolby.com/how-to-prevent-form-spam-by-using-the-honeypot-technique/